# Vertical and Horizontal center align within a div

Tags: css, header, alignment, center

I need some help here. I been trying to get it right for hours and i can't find an efficient solution.

```
<div id="Header">
<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rN0cMMTn_Mw/ToQ6VTghSOI/AAAAAAAAAfs/xl1XMFyn7Jo/s640/18_5_orig.jpg'
/>
 <h1>siajdasdasdasd</h1>

<p>sdhaosidasdas</p>
```

[Example of what im trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/74Rnq/20/)

i want to have a liquid header with an image aligned to the left and a title aligned to the center, but both of em have to align to the middle of the height, no mather if i increase img /div's height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modern browsers you can do it via display:table, table-row table cell:

Modify your html like this:

```
<div id="Header" class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rN0cMMTn_Mw/ToQ6VTghSOI/AAAAAAAAAfs/xl1XMFyn7Jo/s640/18_5_orig.jpg'/>
        </div>
        <div class="cell main">
             <h1>siajdasdasdasd</h1>
             <p>sdhaosidasdas</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#Header {
    background: #DBE6EC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #595959;
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.cell.main {
    width:100%;
}
```

The updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fBN3D/1/). This solution won't work in ie7. There is a older workaround for [vertical align middle](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-valid-solution-en.html), if you have to support ie7.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add few more divs but it works. http://jsfiddle.net/74Rnq/23/

HTML:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rN0cMMTn_Mw/ToQ6VTghSOI/AAAAAAAAAfs/xl1XMFyn7Jo/s640/18_5_orig.jpg'/>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>siajdasdasdasd</h1>
            <p>sdhaosidasdas</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Header {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #DBE6EC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #595959;
    overflow: auto;
}
#Header h1, p {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
#Header p {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#Header img {
    float: left;
    max-height:100px;
}

#Header .wrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; /* Half of wrap div height */
}

#Header .wrap .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -27.5px; /* Half of text div height */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've set #Header height to 200px to show you that it actually centers it.

Comment: But your .text's height is fixed. When you add more text, it doesn't align anymore.

Comment: Yeah, i need the text to center, no mather how much i write there

Answer (score 0):

Make the container div `display: table-cell` and each child div `display: table-cell`. Then you can give the child divs `vertical-align: middle` and they will always be vertically centered.

HTML:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="image">
        <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rN0cMMTn_Mw/ToQ6VTghSOI/AAAAAAAAAfs/xl1XMFyn7Jo/s640/18_5_orig.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div id="title">
       <h1>siajdasdasdasd</h1>
       <p>sdhaosidasdas</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#Header {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #DBE6EC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #595959;
    display: table;
}
#Header h1, p {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #1F1F1F;
}
#Header p {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#Header img {
    float: left;
    max-height:100px;
}
#title{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    width: 100%;
}
#image{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Aaand here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQKhp/)**.